# Left join with different queries from same table where identifier has incremented suffix

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database that has three columns which are intresting for me in this query; Id, Counter and Value. Id is naturally the identifier and is unique. But there are multiple entries in the database that have the initial sequence with an additional suffix added to it.

Each of these entries correspond to a different counter (there can be a maximum of three) which have different values.

An example of what the data might look like;

```
|   id   |   counter   |  value   |
|--------|-------------|----------|
| 1234_1 |  counter_1  |   1.0    |
| 1234_2 |  counter_2  |   7.0    |
| 1234_3 |  counter_3  |   5.0    |
| 2341_1 |  counter_1  |   2.0    |
| 2341_2 |  counter_2  |   6.0    |
| 3412_1 |  counter_1  |   8.0    |
```

What I am trying to achieve is to get the values for each of the counters related to the first 4 digits in the ID. So if I were to get the values for '1234' And '2341' I would get the following result;

```
|   id   |   value_1  |  value_2  |  value_3  |
|  1234  |     1.0    |    7.0    |    5.0    |
|  2341  |     5.0    |    2.0    |    NULL   |
```

I have built a query that uses left joins for each of the counter values, this works fine when retrieving values from one ID, but it will not function when getting values from two different IDs. The result then is more than (in this case) 2 results.

Current query;

```
select LEFT(t1.id,LEN(t1.id)-1)
     , t1.value
     , t2.value
     , t3.value
from (select * from table 
       where id LIKE '1234%'
         AND Counter = 'counter_1') t1
left join (Select * from table Where Counter = 'counter_2') t2 
  on LEFT(t2.id,LEN(t2.id)-1) = LEFT(t1.id,LEN(t1.id)-1)
left join (Select * from table Where Counter = 'counter_3') t3 
  on LEFT(t3.id,LEN(t3.id)-1) = LEFT(t1.id,LEN(t1.id)-1)
```

This works fine and will return the first line of the wanted result. If I however change the first from to include another id;

```
from (select * from table where id LIKE '1234%' OR [Id] LIKE '2341%' ...
```

It will return four values, where the first three have the id '1234'.

I am unable to affect the structure of the database in any way and the reason for choosing left join is to support if the values do not exist for the counters, it should be `NULL`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you want is this:

```
from (select * from [table] 
       where (id LIKE '1234%' OR [Id] LIKE '2341%')
         AND Counter = 'counter_1') t1
```

because AND is done before OR, you get Data where ID is like 1234%, not looking at counter.

Comment: I totally missed this... I know that I noticed it in a previous query that was failing, but this time I guess I missed it. Easy, simple! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I assumed there is always a line with t1.Counter = 'counter_1' :

```
select LEFT(t1.id,LEN(t1.id)-2), t1.value, t2.value, t3.value
from MyTable t1 
left join MyTable t2 on t2.Counter = 'counter_2' and LEFT(t2.id,LEN(t2.id)-2) = LEFT(t1.id,LEN(t1.id)-2)
left join Mytable t3 on t3.Counter = 'counter_3' and LEFT(t3.id,LEN(t3.id)-2) = LEFT(t1.id,LEN(t1.id)-2)
where t1.Counter = 'counter_1'
and t1.[id] LIKE '1234%' OR t1.[Id] LIKE '2341%'
```

If not, you can trick the query like this :

```
select LEFT(t1.id,LEN(t1.id)-2), t1.value, t2.value, t3.value
from (select 1 as 'c') t
left join MyTable t1 on t1.Counter = 'counter_1' and t1.[id] LIKE '1234%' OR t1.[Id] LIKE '2341%'
left join MyTable t2 on t2.Counter = 'counter_2' and LEFT(t2.id,LEN(t2.id)-2) = LEFT(t1.id,LEN(t1.id)-2)
left join Mytable t3 on t3.Counter = 'counter_3' and LEFT(t3.id,LEN(t3.id)-2) = LEFT(t1.id,LEN(t1.id)-2)
```